# React Array wont update, when adding items to it

Tags: reactjs

I have made To-Do list with react, but when I submit new entry, it wont show on the list. I have no clue where the problem is.

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
```

This array doesn't get updated like it should:

```
    this.state ={
      items:["item1", "item2"]
    };
  }
```

Here I add new task:

```
  addTask = (task) => {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  items: prevState.items.concat([task])
}));


}

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <AddTodo addNew ={this.addTask}/>
        <ShowEntries entries={this.state.items}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AddTodo extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
this.handeAddNew = this.handeAddNew.bind(this);
    this.state ={
      task: ""
    };
  }
```

Here I update the state, it works fine:

```
  update(e){
    this.setState({
      task: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

Here I have passed the addTask function as a prop. This might be where the problem is?

```
  handeAddNew(){
    this.props.addNew(this.state.task);
    this.setState({
      task: ""
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text"
        onChange={this.update.bind(this)}></input>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ShowEntries class works fine too:

```
class ShowEntries extends React.Component{
  render(){
    var list =this.props.entries.map((task) =>{
      return <li>{task}</li>
    });
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {list}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TodoList
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind addTask function.

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
}
```

Or change addTask to arrow function.
like

```
addTask = (task) => {
  /* add task*/
}
```

handleAddNew also needs binding.

```
this.handleAddNew = this.handleAddNew.bind(this);
```

Comment: I missed handleAddNew in AddTodo component... You should bind it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on previous state to update the next state, you must use [functional `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) in React, like so:

```
  addTask = (task) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat([task])
    }));
  }
```

That, along with binding all functions used (preferrably inside the constructor itself), should solve your issue.

Comment: what is that prevState attribute?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: thank you for letting me know from prevState, but unofortunately this didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: can you pleas share a working pen or fiddle so that we can debug your code ?

Comment: Ok why do you have `items: prevState.items.concat([task])` instead of just `items: prevState.items.concat(task)` ? You are just passing a string ryt ? (although I think this is not the issue)

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled handeAddNew.

make it `handleAddNew` also make sure you bind your methods `handleAddNew = () => { //code  }`

Comment: if thats the issue we shoould close this as a typo